# Eliminating text in a list with .replace and wildcards

Tags: python

I have a list of the following form in python:

```
x = ['[a] 123', '[b] 456', '[c] 789']
```

and I want to get a list that looks like

```
xclean = ['123', '456', '789']
```

I'm currently trying to strip off the [*]'s using this:

```
xclean=[]
for item in x:
    cut_item = item.replace('[*]', '')
    xlistclean.append(cut_item)
```

Thinking that the * would signify anything between the opening and closing bracket. Instead, I get the same list with no change; probably because it is searching for the literal string '[*]'. 
Any ideas on better ways to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, regular `str.replace` doesn't have wildcard functionality. You could use `re.sub`, which *does* have wildcards:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = ['[a] 123', '[b] 456', '[c] 789']
>>> x = [re.sub(r"\[.\] ", "", s) for s in x]
>>> print x
['123', '456', '789']
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
x = ['[a] 123', '[b] 456', '[c] 789']

import re
def cleaner(list):
    return [re.findall(r'] (\d+)',x)[0] for x in list]

xclean = cleaner(x)
```

Comment: Try to explain what your answer does more clearly, especially in a case like this where you are introducing new functionality (including the `re` module) which a beginner probably wouldn't be familiar with.

Comment: Please don't use `list` as a variable name as it shadows the built-in `list` type.